# Show that $\frac{d \sin{z}}{dz}=\cos{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I have this:

We know that $\sin{z}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}$, $\cos{z}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$.

Let $z=x+iy$, $\sin{z}=\frac{e^{ix}e^{-y}-e^{-ix}e^y}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\cos{x}(e^{-y}-e^y)+i\sin{x}(e^{-y}+e^y))$, where $u=\frac{1}{2}\cos{x}(e^{-y}-e^y)$,$v=\frac{1}{2}\sin{x}(e^{-y}+e^y)$.

And $f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, so i have to $f'(z)=\frac{1}{2}(\sin{x}(e^y-e^{-y})+i\cos{x}(e^{-y}+e^y))$, but $\cos{z}=\frac{1}{2}(\cos{x}(e^{-y}+e^y)+i\sin{x}(e^{-y}-e^y))$.

I don't know if there is something I am doing wrong, is there any way to get to this result by this method?

Comment: You are wrong because $$\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2\color{red}{i}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Remark that ${d\over{dz}}e^z=e^z$, this follows from the fact that $e^z=\sum {z^n\over{n!}}$, and you can derive it terms by terms since it converges normally.

${d\over{dz}}{1\over {2i}}({{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}})$

$={1\over {2i}}(ie^{iz}-(-i)e^{-iz})=\cos z.$